# Problema com ViewScoped RequestScoped e Session

Tags: java, jsf-2.2

Tenho o seguinte Cenário:

Um DataTable onde possui um botão o qual executa um método do Bean, porém este DataTable esta utilizando um Paginação com Lazy Loading, porém de acordo a anotação de sessão que utilizo o método do botão não é executado ou a sessão é encerrada.

Se utilizo no Bean a anotação:

```
javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

Toda a busca para popular o DataTable é executada, porém o botão de edição quando acionado não executa o método do Bean.

Já se utilizo no Bean a anotação:

```
javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
```

A busca não é executada por completa, porém o acionamento do botão editar executa o método do Bean.

Faço a criação da Sessão através de um DAOFactory

```
public static DocumentoDAO criarDocumentoDAO() {
   DocumentoDAOHibernate documentoDAO  = new DocumentoDAOHibernate();
   documentoDAO.setSession(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());
   return documentoDAO;
}
```

Alguma sugestão de como resolver?

Comment: Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando `@RequestScoped`, seus dados estão visíveis apenas durante a requisição.
Para manipulação de tabelas em uma tela, eu indico o `@ViewScoped`, que manterá seus dados visíveis enquanto permanescer na tela.
Leia mais a respeito do escopo dos `ManagedBeans` [aqui](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/jsf-annotations)